# Opencart doesn't work on hosting

Tags: php, header, opencart

I have a following problem:

I wrote a script related products for Opencart. This script select products based on minimum price and on maximum price that are prewritten by administrator. Also administrator must enter categories of those related products. For example if you chose a motherboard you will see hard drives, cooling systems ets. When I am trying to save those settings in my admin page I get the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: related_kv4nt_id_3 in /home/eplus/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_catalog_product.php on line 145
>
> Notice: Undefined index: related_kv4nt_id_4 in
>   /home/eplus/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_catalog_product.php
>   on line 145
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/eplus/public_html/admin/index.php:83) in
>   /home/eplus/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 28
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/eplus/public_html/admin/index.php:83) in
>   /home/eplus/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 29

`related_kv4nt_id_3` is the number of product category that will be showen. For example `related_kv4nt_id_1` is block that shows motherboards
`related_kv4nt_id_2` shows hard drives ets.
There are 4 of them. What can solve this problem?

When you trying to save the settings there is only category gets saved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @BogdanOnyshenko It means, that there is already an answer to this question.

Comment: Well I would not ask it if it would help me. And plus my problem is that it works perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: Does anyone know why it happened and what to do?

Comment: Have you tried disabling PHPs error checking?

Comment: isn't a error undefined index self explanatory ? you are using index related_kv4nt_id_3 in array but the error does not have any element named related_kv4nt_id_3. its programming error, not hosting error. moreover this index related_kv4nt_id_3 is your custom made index so nobody can help without having a look on the code.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined index errors happen when you try to use an array index which you have not created.

So if you have an array with the key foo and then called the array key bar you would get an index notice because you have not defined bar in your array.

So in this case it could be your data array does not have id_3 and id_4 of your custom variables.

The header information warnings occur because you cannot have any output to the page before the headers are sent. In your case the header notifications come up because of the notices. Fix the notices and the header warnings will solve themselves.